# Ansible hosts file parsing not working as expected

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am having a strange issue. I have a 'hosts' file with multiple groups in it.
For some reason, when I am using 'ansible-playbook playbook.yml -l GROUPNAME', ansible applies the playbook to all hosts in the 'hosts' file.

hosts file

```
all:
  children:
   GROUP1:
    children:
        webservers:
            hosts:
                hostname1:
        sqlservers:
            hosts:
                hostname2:

   GROUP2:
    children:
        webservers:
            hosts:
                hostname3:
                hostname4:

   GROUP3:
    children:
        webservers:
            hosts:
                hostname5:
                hostname6:
        sqlservers:
            hosts:
                hostname7:
```

ansible log:

```
Positional arguments: playbook.yml
verbosity: 4
connection: smart
timeout: 10
become_method: sudo
tags: ('all',)
inventory: ('hostsfile',)
subset: GROUP1
forks: 5
1 plays in playbook.yml
```

In the 'playbook.yml' file I do have 'hosts: all' but in a different job I don't have this issue.

Ansible does notice the Subset I indicated but is not filtering it, instead it is running the playbook successfully against all hosts.

I combed through the web for the entire day yesterday and could not find the problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not an Ansible expert... but your hosts file doesn't match the formats in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html ? Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Using the `ansible-inventory -i ./the-inventory-file --list` is a great troubleshooting tool for understanding how ansible sees the inventory and their vars

Comment: @mdaniel , thank you for the tip. When I run this I get no hosts listed:
'all:
  children:
    ungrouped: {}'
But when I run 
'ansible GROUPNAME -i .hosts.yml --list-hosts'
I get ths list of the hosts. I am not sure why ansible is not grouping the hosts.

Comment: For 100% clarity, the `-i ./the-inventory-file` should be `-i .hosts.yml` in your case, but I didn't know the filename. When I run `ansible-inventory` on the yaml you provided above, it cheerfully emits the JSON I expect, so there's obviously something else going on

Comment: @mdaniel, my file name is hosts.yaml. I run the 'ansible-inventory' command with the '-y' switch in order to signify it is a yaml file.

Comment: The `-y` doesn't _signify_ it's yaml, it causes yaml _output_ for things like `--list`; ansible supports a wide variety of inventory file formats and it would almost defeat the purpose if one had to specify the input file format manually each time

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to this problem on my own.
By default, Ansible is parsing the hosts file using a set of inventory plugins until it will succeed.
By specifying the plugin in 'ansible.cfg':

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = yaml
```

The problem was solved, I am not sure why.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory.html